# Handle http response in Spring Integration

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I have a `http:outbound-gateway` as follows:

```
 <int:channel id="fromEmployeeChannel" />
 <int-http:outbound-gateway
        url="localhost:8080/api/employees" request-channel="fromEmployeeChannel"
        http-method="POST" expected-response-type="java.lang.String" reply-channel="employeeAdded" >
 </int-http:outbound-gateway>
```

How do I handle the different HTTP response status? Also how to handle error if I receive some error like 404 Not Found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler` populates `response status` to the `replyMessage` headers:

```
replyBuilder.setHeader(org.springframework.integration.http.HttpHeaders.STATUS_CODE, httpResponse.getStatusCode());
```

So, you can do `<header-value-router>` downstream the `<int-http:outbound-gateway>` to send response to different channels for different logic.

`404` and similar are handled by `DefaultResponseErrorHandler` (the default one) from `RestTemplate` and are thrown as Exception from there: `HttpClientErrorException` or `HttpServerErrorException`, respectivally. Or even like `RestClientException("Unknown status code [" + statusCode + "]")`.

First of all this exception is thrown to the upstream, e.g. `<gateway>` or `error-channel` on polling or message-driven endpoint.

But from other side you can do some logic with them exactly here on the `<int-http:outbound-gateway>`. For this purpose it has `<int-http:request-handler-advice-chain>` and there is built-in `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` with ability to do something `onFailureExpression`: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#message-handler-advice-chain